# How can I sort out a resolution problem with Icewind Dale in Wine?

Tags: wine, xubuntu, games

A lot of the games I like to play don't run too well on my Xubuntu laptop, so I decided that I was going to play Icewind Dale.  I installed it, but when I go to play, 2/3 of the graphics is off the top of the screen.  Apparently, Icewind Dale has a windowed mode, but I don't know how to enable it out of the screen, so now I'm just kind of stuck.  I'm running Wine 1.5.5.  Anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely some things that might be helpful for you regarding Icewind Dale in `wine`:

1) If the windowed mode in your game is not available in the options, you can run `wine` in windowed mode via the 'virtual desktop' setting (see further below). However, before you alter the `wine` setting, you must also enable windowed mode by running the Icewind Dale config tool in the Icewind Dale game folder in your `.wine` prefix.

[image]

Now, go to Wine configuration in the Xubuntu `Wine` menu, go to Applications and select your Icewind Dale executable and create a profile for it; in that application profile you can have custom settings for audio, graphics,etc (i.e. all the settings tabs that are available). In the graphics section you can set a 'windowed' mode via the 'virtual desktop' setting; just set the resolution, as the screenshot below shows, and save your settings.

[image]

2) Another possibility is that you could run Icewind Dale in [GemRB](http://www.gemrb.org/wiki/doku.php?id=start), which is a native SDL port of the Infinity Engine, which Icewind Dale uses. You could use your existing game files, and install further infinity engine games with `wine`, and then point `gemrb` to the files, as noted [here](http://www.gemrb.org/wiki/doku.php?id=installation). There is also a gemrb [launcher](http://www.gemrb.org/wiki/doku.php?id=launcher) that may be useful. It is possible to successfully play through Icewind Dale 1, but not the expansions. This is definitely a possibility for you and any fans of the Infinity Engine games. Further details on how well the games are supported is noted [here](http://www.gemrb.org/wiki/doku.php?id=changelog), and the Baldur's Gate series run particularly well in gemRB.

Icewind Dale running in windowed mode with `wine`.

[image]